# Retrieve href from a specific table data cell in a dynamic HTML table in a website

Tags: javascript, html, href

I like to retrieve the href from a specific table cell data from a dynamic HTML table in a webpage.  For oversimplified example below, I like to find a table cell named "Report BBB" and retrieve its href.  Any example codes in Javascript would be appreciated.  Thank you!

```html
<tr>
  <td><a href="javascript:openWin('http://AAA')">Report AAA</a></td>
  <td><a href="javascript:openWin('http://BBB')">Report BBB</a></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: what have you tried so far? `.getAttribute("href")` will get you the href of an element while you can search for the innerHTML...

Comment: There are many ways to do it. You have to try something and explain where you're having difficulty

Comment: I advise against using pseudo protocol `javascript:` inside the href attribute. There are disadvantages.

Comment: I scrapped a webpage with UrlFetchApp and then used .search and . substring to find the text, hoping that it would read the whole strings around the text so that I can later extract my desired href string only.   But it didn't provide any match.

Answer (score 0):

#### Method 1:

Get all the `a elements` from the table and `loop` to check if the `innerHTML` is equal to the value you want, *(check `target_value`)*. if `true`, get the `href` value of the `element` *(check the variable `val`)*

```js
var all_links = document.querySelectorAll('table a');
var target_value = "Report BBB";
var val;

all_links.forEach(element => {
  if(element.innerHTML == target_value){
    val = element.getAttribute("href");
    console.log(val);
  } 
});
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="javascript:openWin('http://AAA')">Report AAA</a></td>
      <td><a href="javascript:openWin('http://BBB')">Report BBB</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

#### Method 2:

If the element (`a`) contains more text, like: *Report BBB and more...* *(Check the HTML below)*

```
<td><a href="javascript:openWin('http://BBB')">Report BBB and more</a></td>
```

Then you can use the `includes` function to check.

```js
var all_links = document.querySelectorAll('table a');
var target_value = "Report BBB";
var val;

all_links.forEach(element => {
  if(element.innerHTML.includes(target_value)){
    val = element.getAttribute("href");
    console.log(val);
  } 
});
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="javascript:openWin('http://AAA')">Report AAA</a></td>
      <td><a href="javascript:openWin('http://BBB')">Report BBB and more</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

##### Note:

If the `HTML` letters case may change, then use `toUpperCase()` or `toLowerCase()` when you check. See:

HTML:

```
<td><a href="javascript:openWin('http://BBB')">RePoRt BbB</a></td>
```

JS

```
var target_value = "report bbb";

if(element.innerHTML.toUpperCase() == target_value.toUpperCase())
```

Example:

```js
var all_links = document.querySelectorAll('table a');
var target_value = "report bbb";
var val;

all_links.forEach(element => {
  if(element.innerHTML.toUpperCase() == target_value.toUpperCase()){
    val = element.getAttribute("href");
    console.log(val);
  } 
});
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="javascript:openWin('http://AAA')">Report AAA</a></td>
      <td><a href="javascript:openWin('http://BBB')">RePoRt BbB</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you!  The codes or even my original are working well with public website table data scraping, but they don't work with my intended financial website with a private account.  I realize that my private financial website doesn't allow any scraping.